# Can I check when someone followed me on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I recently came across a user who follows me on Twitter.

[image: Twitter user follows me]

I don't ever remember getting a notification when they started following me. I'm not even sure how long they've been following my profile.

**Is there a way to check when a user started following me on Twitter?**

Comment: I wish I could answer this question. Moving forward however, I've found IFTTT's notifications of new followers far more reliable than Twitter's. So I use those instead.